# Print statements not being executed in real time

Tags: haskell, io

I have a wrapper around `readCreateProcessWithExitCode` that does an early exit whenever a non-zero exit code is returned, and returns the `stdout` output

```
import System.Process

runShell :: String -> String -> IO String
runShell cmd msg = do
  (ec, r, err) <- readCreateProcessWithExitCode (shell cmd) ""
  when (isFailure ec) (error $ msg <> ": " <> err)
  return r
```

From the docs page, `readCreateProcessWithExitCode` seems to be similar to the simpler `readProcess`, which claims to block until the forked process terminates.

Now the issue arises whenever I try to interleave logs to `stdout` myself using `putStrLn`.

```
fn :: IO ()
fn = do
  void $ runShell "lightweight" "err1"
  print "log1"
  void $ runShell "expensive" "err2"
  print "log2"
```

Assuming both commands executions are successful, and that the second one takes a few second to execute, the function should log `"log1"` almost immediately after running `lightweight`, wait a few seconds and then print `"log2"`. That's not the case however - it appears that logs are being 'suspended' and only printed at the end of program execution, all at once.

I thought lazy evaluation had something to do with it, but explicitly evaluating the results of `putStrLn` didn't help either

`() <- putStrLn "log1"`

Comment: I'm not sure this is lazy evaluation. This might just have been the *buffering* of the result. Depending on the shell, operating system, and handler, writing data to the stdout does not per se immediately prints on the shell.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're absolutely right. `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` seems to have solved the issue

Comment: Keep in mind that disabling the buffering may negatively impact performance if the output is large. Consider running `hFlush stdout` after the `print`s. (Also, use `putStrLn "..."` instead if you don't want the strings to be quoted and escaped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Willem Van Onsem pointed out in a comment, there's some buffering going on with `stdout` by default. It can be disabled using

```
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

Comment: `LineBuffering` is probably a better tradeoff between efficiency and promptness than `NoBuffering`. It is the default for stdout unless you run your program in an unusual way -- e.g. as part of a pipeline.